# A short, colloquial way of saying "make up your own mind"

Tags: synonyms

I'm trying to find a short (1-2 word) way of saying "make up your own mind" (as opposed to having other people unduly influence you). I want a positive connotation, so "figure it out" doesn't work.

More specifically, a really short way of saying: "examine the evidence about this contentious subject and form your own opinion". "You Decide" is along the right lines.

Any ideas?

Comment: These are my favorite one-, two-, and three-word ways to say what you seem to be asking about: "Adjudicate!" "You decide."  "Speak, O Muse!"

Comment: *You* decide. :)

Comment: But seriously, *decide for yourself* is what one would instinctively and naturally say most of the time, to mean "make up your mind, on your own."

Comment: That's for you to decide.

Comment: Keep calm and think for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...find a short (1-2 word) way of saying “make up your own mind”

One or two words is quite limiting, so some of the following use three.  However, the two-word phrase *[due diligence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/due_diligence)* [which, technically, refers to  “A legally binding process during which a potential buyer evaluates the assets and liabilities of a company”] often is used figuratively or more generally to mean to study something carefully and thoroughly before reaching a decision.

Possible imperative phrasings:

> • Decide for yourself
>   • Use due diligence
>   • Be openminded
>   • Think independently
>   • Study the issues
>   • Consider carefully

Answer (score 0):

> - Your conclusion!!

may suggest the idea;  short for *draw your own conclusion*.

also the expressions:

> - You choose!! or Your choice!!